# Why does the exit status check in my Bash prompt function also evaluate to true?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I'm new to the bash commands and the functions. I have two functions and trying to display them in my terminal

```
git_branch()
```

and

```
highlightExitCode()
```

Here I want to change prompt setting by `export PS1`, with these two functions. I'm able to get branch name and also the emoji from `highlightExitCode()` but the emoji displayed is always from the else and never executes if part.

Can someone let me know what part I'm doing wrong here.

```
export PS1='[\@][\u] [\W]$(git_branch) $(highlightExitCode)\$ '

git_branch() 
{
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}

highlightExitCode()
{
  exit_code=$?
  if [ $exit_code -ne 0 ]
    then
      echo -en '\xf0\x9f\x98\xb1 '
  else
    echo -en '\xf0\x9f\x98\x80 '
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`highlightExitCode` is getting the exit status of the last command run, which is `git_branch` while constructing the value of the prompt.

Use `PROMPT_COMMAND` instead to build a prompt dynamically. In your .bashrc file,

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=build_prompt

git_branch() 
{
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}

highlightExitCode()
{
  if [ "$1" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo -en '\xf0\x9f\x98\xb1 '
  else
    echo -en '\xf0\x9f\x98\x80 '
  fi
}

build_prompt () {
  last_exit=$?
  PS1='[\@][\u] [\W]'
  PS1+=$(git_branch)
  PS1+=" $(highlightExitCode "$last_exit")"
  PS1+='\$ '
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`$?`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_003f) is the exit status of the "most recently executed foreground pipeline". Since you always (successfully) run `git_branch` right before `highlightExitCode`, `$?` is always `0`. The behaviour you want is roughly as follows:

```
$ exitcode() { (($? == 0)) && echo ":)" || echo ":("; }
$ PS1='$(exitcode) \$ '
:) $ false
:( $ true
:) $
```

but with an additional command as part of `PS1`.

To achieve that, you can do the following:

- Create these three functions, for example as part of your `~/.bashrc`:

  ```
  git_branch() {
      git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
  }

  smiley() {
      (($1 == 0)) &&  echo ':)' ||  echo ':('
  }

  set_prompt() {
      local exitstatus=$?
      PS1='$(git_branch) '"$(smiley "$exitstatus")"' \$ '
  }
  ```
- Set the `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable to `set_prompt` (probably also in `~/.bashrc`)

Now you have a prompt that behaves as follows:

```
(master) :) $ false
(master) :( $ true
(master) :) $
```

The main trick is to store the exit status that determines the smiley behaviour before doing anything else.

---

As an aside, a cleaner way of getting the name of the current branch is

```
git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD 2>/dev/null
```